# Regex matching two strings in one group

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match two strings from a text file.I wrote a function to perform the matching for both strings. Only one string is printed and the other one is ignored although the sequence works : matched the string and tested with an online regex tester.

**NVRAM_info.txt**

```
NvRam is available, BlockSize is : 0x00001000
            Max. datasize is : 0x00040000
```

### #

```
NVRAM_INFO = "NVRAM_info.txt"
import re

def Capture(Form,File_name,Fil,index):
    B = " "

  with open(File_name) as Fil:
    p = re.compile(Form) 
    for line in Fil:
        m = p.match(line)
        if m != None:
            B= m.group(1)
            if index == 2 :
               logging.info("the maximal Data size of the NVRAM is:%s",B)

            else:
               logging.info("the NVRAM Blocksize is:%s",B)


        break
    else:
        logging.info("couldnt find the Maximal userspace memory size")
return B
Maxsize = Capture(r"\s{1,}Max. datasize is :\s{1,}([a-zA-Z_0-9]{1,})","NVRAM_info.txt",NVRAM_INFO,2)
BlockSize = Capture(r"NvRam is available, BlockSize is :\s{1,}([a-zA-Z_0-9]{1,})","NVRAM_info.txt",NVRAM_INFO,1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason your code is so convoluted?  Your Capture function doesn't return anything, so the assignments will assign `None`.  Reading the entire file into memory again each time you want to capture something is ... odd, and inefficient. Maybe you could think about how to reduce this to just the simplest possible code (three statements?) for this question; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the use of the `Fil` parameter?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : the Fil parameter is the files name

Comment: @tripleee: im a beginner in Programming ..if u have other ideas would you please share them ? thx

Comment: @MomoEssassi: ok, and what is the `File_name` parameter?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: file_name param is the path.

Comment: The immediate problem is that the `break` terminates after the first line.  Is your indentation in the question correct?  I'm thinking you would get a syntax error for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NVRAM_INFO = "NVRAM_info.txt"
import re

file = open(NVRAM_INFO, 'r')
test_str = file.read();
p = re.compile(u'BlockSize is : (\dx\d+)\n.*?Max. datasize is : (\dx\d+)', re.DOTALL)

g = re.findall(p, test_str)

Maxsize = g[0][1]
BlockSize = g[0][0]
print(Maxsize)
print(BlockSize)
```

Output:

```
0x00040000
0x00001000
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers given, though work, can be made more ***efficient*** as follows. If `s` is the line being searched, then

```
reg = r'BlockSize is : (0x\d{8})\n\s*Max\. datasize is : (0x\d{8})'

In [62]: pat = re.compile(reg)

In [64]: blocksize, maxsize = pat.search(s).groups()

In [65]: blocksize, maxsize
Out[65]: ('0x00001000', '0x00040000')
```

Now, that we know it works, let's see if it's more efficient. (Comparing with @Tim007 's answer)

```
In [66]: timeit pat.search(s).groups()
The slowest run took 8.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an 
intermediate result is being cached 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.38 µs per loop

In [74]: timeit  re.findall(p, s) # @Tim007's answer
The slowest run took 4.94 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an 
intermediate result is being cached 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.51 µs per loop
```

So it is about **2.31 times faster**. The use of `\d{8}` in place of `\d+` makes it efficient because *more specific it is, faster it becomes*. And secondly this version is less problematic because it *doesn't* use the `re.DOTALL` flag, rather makes do with `\n`.

> If given a choice, it’s usually better to define your regular expression pattern
>   so that it works correctly without the need for extra flags. (*Beazly*)